# How can i make video file from captured video stream udp packet?

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to extract video stream data from captured udp packets.
I captured packet between Ios App(KY FPV) <-> Drone(XKJ Drone) using airodump-ng, wireless lan(Panda pau06).

So I tried to extract video stream data using python.
App <-> Drone use udp protocol, not RTP.

I decompiled KY FPV Apps, App stored file using .mp4 or .avi.

I made some code to extract video stream. but video file is not working. i don't know what is the problem.

Any advice?

```
import struct



def open_cap():
    cap = open("./filtered.pcap", "rb")
    data = cap.read()
    print("[*] File Open Success")
    return data

def UDP_Packets(data): # find udp packets
    if data.find(b'\x88\x02\x3c'):
        idx = data.find(b'\x88\x02\x3c')

    try:
        length = struct.unpack('<l', data[idx-4:idx])[0] #
        #print(f'UDP Packet Length: {length}')
    except:
        return [], [], -1
    packet = data[idx:idx+length]
    data = data[idx+length:]

    return data, packet, idx

def Extract_data(packets):
    h264 = []
    for packet in packets:
        if b'\x93\x0x38' in packet[0x3e:]:
            h264.append(packet[0x3e:])
 
    print("[*] H.264 Data Extract")
    return h264

def save(H264):
    with open("H264", "wb") as f:
        for h264 in H264:
            for bd in h264:
                f.write(struct.pack("B",bd))
    print("[*] H.264 Video Saved")

def main():
    packets = []
    cnt = 1
    data = open_cap()

    while True:
        cnt = cnt + 1
        data, temp, idx = UDP_Packets(data)
        print(cnt)
        if idx == -1:
            break
        packets.append(temp)
    print("[*] Packets Found")
    H264 = Extract_data(packets)
    save(H264)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

And this is the captured packet.
This picture is one of the udp packet.
[image]

This is error.

[image: error 1]
[image]

Comment: Your code contains several magical constants, can you explain where you came up with these?

Comment: you mean \x93\x01\x38? or \x88\x02\x3c? \x88\x02\x3c is start of packet.

Comment: Yeah, those two exactly; how do you know these things, and are you sure these sequences don't occur by coincidence elsewehere in the captured data?

Comment: 1. I use wireshark, and see captured packet. all of the udp packet data start \x88\x02\x3c; 2. yes i'm pretty sure